# Netbeans installer not seeing jdk

Tags: java, netbeans

When I run the Netbeans 8.2 installer,
I get a message saying the JDK is not in the location that I browsed to.

I visually verified that JDK was installed here (and I type `java -version` and verified it was there.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

When I typed **java -version** I got:

```
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)
```

I placed the path under JAVA_HOME in Environment Variables on `Control Panel->System`.

It can't see the files when I browse in the installer but I can see the java files there when I use file explorer.

Is this a compatibility issue between JDK and Netbeans or maybe permission issue?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think it looks permission issue..

Comment: This is not _"a compatibility issue between jdk and netbeans"_, but I agree with Anil (and you); this looks like a permissions issue. Try installing Java to another directory (e.g. **C:\Java\JDK8**) to see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: I dropped back a version and used an installer that sets up jdk and netbeans at the same time.  It works now but with an older version.  Maybe I can update jdk to the new version and it will solve the problem that way.

Comment: That path is for the JRE, not for the JDK.